# Sending Email Using SendGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, sendgrid

I'm trying to send email from sendgrid as follows-

```
public static async Task<int> SendEmail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string emailMessage, string subject)
{
    try
    {
        // Create the email object first, then add the properties.
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        // Add the message properties.
        myMessage.AddTo(toEmail);
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
        myMessage.Subject = subject;
        myMessage.Html = emailMessage;
        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkUserId"];
        var pswd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NetworkUserPwd"];
        var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostName"];
        // Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd, domain);
        // Create an Web transport for sending email.
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        if (transportWeb != null)
            await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
        else
        {
            await Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        //throw ex;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here I'm using async and await, I got mail successfully but I'm expecting return value as 1. I think my debugger hitch into await.

Comment: There should be no way (if this is being used correctly) that this code should not return `1`. If your not getting that value then I'm guessing you have some kind of deadlock scenario going on. Without seeing the calling code though this is just a guess. It'd help if you were more clear on what exactly is happening here

Comment: Actully, I lost my debugger at "await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);" and not found any response where i called this method. I think await is not working here.

Comment: *I'm guessing you have some kind of deadlock scenario going on. Without seeing the calling code though this is just a guess*

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to await the result of 0, your code should be:

```
    public static async Task<int> SendEmail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string emailMessage, string subject) {
        try {
            // Same as your example
            if (transportWeb != null)
                await transportWeb.DeliverAsync("");
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) {
            //throw ex;
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but not working actually I've lost my debugger after "await transportWeb.DeliverAsync("");".